# How to use jmlc, jmlunit with OpenJML?

Tags: java, jml

I have installed OpenJML tool (http://openjml.org/) for the Eclipse and was using it and it worked quite well.

However, now I need to call the *jmlc* and *jmlunit* tools from command line. As I see from the search in Internet these tools should be located at some directory of JML,I should add them to PATH and use normally by calling the corresponding commands. But once I download OpenJML I have only 3 jar files and no directory at all. Also, from the official JML page there is no other link to download some other version rather than OpenJML. It seems to me that I don't get something obvious.

So, the question is how I can find these tools to run them on command line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For `jmlc`, use the -compile flag.
You can also add it as in alias in your ~/.bash_profile:

`alias jmlc="java -jar $JML_HOME/openjml.jar -compile"`